Correct way to parallelize request processing in Flask
I have a Flask service that receives GET requests, and I want to scale the QPS on that endpoint (on a single machine/container). Should I use a python ThreadPoolExecutor or ProcessPoolExecutor, or something else? The GET request just retrieves small pieces of data from a cache backed by a DB. Is there anything specific to Flask that should be taken into account?

You probably want to start by measuring the thing you want to improve - what's the current QPS, and have you identified any obvious bottlenecks in the current request pipeline?

remember ProcessPoolExecutor requires non-trivial state synchronization, it really depends on how much state is being shared and how much work is being done in the workers.

@MathiasR.Jessen Very good point, you are right. I'll get on to that.

@AhmedAEK The threads really just to each do a simply select ... from db where user_id = xyz each time the /GET endpoint is reached.

Neither.
Flask will serve one request per worker (or more, but depending on the worker type) - the way you set-it up, either with gunicorn, wsgi or awsgi is what is responsible for the number of parallel requests your app can process.
Inside your app, you don't change anything - your views will be called as independent processes, independent threads or independent async tasks, depending on how you setup your server - that is where you have to tinker with the configurations.
Using another concurrency strategy would only make sense if each request would have calculations and data fetching which could themselves be parallelized, inside the same request.
Check how is your deployment configured, and pick the best option for you (all things being equal, pick the easiest one): https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/stable/deploying/   (also, I would not recomend "mod_wsgi" among those options - it is super complex and old tech)

If I still use a thread pool executor, nothing bad will happen? I will just have too many parallelization levels?

no - you are fine with a threadpool executor to which to submit tasks inside your view code. Just do not create a  new executor inside the view code - that should be a process-wide resource.
Also, keep in mind that functions run in the executor can't access context-information Flask makes automatically available for each view (i.e. any `request.* attribute, for example)  - all information your off-thread functions need have to be passed as explicit arguments.

What do you mean by "view code"? I am not super familiar with Flask.

The "view" in web applications is the function that gets called by the framework to ultimatelly generate your response. In Flask, they are the functions decorated with @app.route(...)

Thank you! That's indeed where I put the threadpool executor.

Yes - it is were you MUST NOT put it - you have to create the executor outside this funciton, and use it inside the function.
Forget about the with command to go with the executor - it is not necessary in this case.

Yes - sorry about the confusion, I created the pool outside the @app.route(...) functions and use it inside.
